# laravel 4 validation unique ignore and where

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to my values before i submit them to my database. My field requires a very specific type of validation and so my question consists of two pieces.

My table has 3 fields: id, name, parent_id

Currently I'm using these lines to validate my variables:

```
protected static $rules = array(
    'name' => 'Required|Min:1|Max:255|unique:table,name'
);
```

And it works fine...

Except, this also disables the ability to edit this record because if I don't change the name it's identical...
1) I need to ignore the record's id (this has to be a variable, not a fixed integer)

In the docs i found this:
http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique

this works, but it's not a variable:

```
'name' => 'Required|Min:1|Max:255|unique:table,fieldname,1'
```

and on the laravel forums i found this:
http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1868

so i tried this:

```
'name' => 'Required|Min:1|Max:255|unique:table,fieldname,$input["table_id"]'
```

and

```
'name' => 'Required|Min:1|Max:255|unique:table,fieldname,'.$input["table_id"]
```

however this is not working for me...

2) The name has to be unique for every record with the same parent_id, I would also like to do this using variables. According to the docs I should be able to do something like:

```
'name' => 'Required|Min:1|Max:255|unique:table,fieldname,'.$input["table_id"] .',parent_id,'.$input["parent_id"]
```

But this doesn't seem to work...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

in the first code you used the 'protected' word, so maybe you are in a class validating your data

Try to do something like this

```
public static $rules = array(
    //You don't need min:1 rule since you have the required rule
    'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:TABLE_NAME',
    ...
);

public function save(array $options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->attributes['id'])) { //do if you updating data
        static::$rules['name'].=',name,' . $this->attributes['id'];
    }
    return parent::save($options);
}
```

Comment: Great! thanks, so now I've managed to ignore the record I'm editing.
Would you have any idea how to validate my record so that it's not unique for the table but only for everything with the same parent_id?
Thanks again!

Comment: when using Ardent, you should put that into the `beforeValidate()` method.